# Which statistical test to use for fish experiment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interpretation

I did an experiment of prey preferences on archerfish (they spit water jets at prey), basically I have a set of data for 6 sessions, and for each session I recorded the amount of spits per each prey item
Which statistical analysis would be most suitable in here?

I basicallt want to find out which prey item is being chosen most frequently and have a comparison with the other choices

I also have a set of data for each session saying how much time it took the fish to start spitting; the time is decreasing and I wanted to run some stats to clearly show it, was thining maybe a simple correlation would be alright? Showing the change in time in relation to progressing sessions?

I'm really not good with stats and always find it confusing to decide on the test type.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to learn from you data? In other words, why measure anything about the fish at all?

Comment: "Which statistical analysis would be most suitable in here?" First explain (and put it in your post as well): *why did you do this experiment*? / What were you trying to find out?